# how can i get a good sound in ubuntu?

Tags: sound

How can i get a good sound quality in ubuntu 16.0 LTS. Is there any kind of equalizer software for linux ?

I used alsa mixer , but it did not bring satisfactory changes in the sound quality.

Answer (score 0):

Give [PulseAudio equalizer](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/system-wide-pulseaudio-equalizer.html) a try !

> PulseAudio Equalizer provides a 15 band equalizer interface for the LADSPA sound processing functionality of PulseAudio. It supports enabling or disabling equalized audio on-the-fly, comes with some built-in presets (based on VLC's built-in equalizer), supports saving your own custom presets for later use, can be used for the current session only or permanently, etc.

To install, open terminal and run below command :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

[image]

<sub>Image taken from webupd8.org</sub>